# How can I round this result to 2 decimal places code example

Tags: android

How can i round off this particular code to show only 2 decimal places.

```
double sum = ((3.141592654/4*(tbmODInput)*(tbmODInput))-(3.141592654/4*(pipeODInput)*(pipeODInput)))*muckUpInput;

volume_per_meter_result.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
```

Comment: Use `String.format("%.2f", sum)` instead of `String.valueOf(sum)`

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin

```
val value = 3.14159265358979323

// round to 2 decimal: 3.14
val formated = "Rounded is: %.2f".format(value)
```

Java

```java
double value = 3.14159265358979323;

// round to 2 decimal: 3.14
String formated = String.format("Rounded is: %.2f", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Java:

```
double value = 3.141592654;

String formated = String.format("Rounded is: %.2f", value);
```

For Kotlin:

```
val value = 3.141592654

val formattedText= "Rounded is: %.2f".format(value)
```

Comment: Why u copy my answer and edit it after I edit my self ?)

Comment: I did not copy the answer, this is the correct answer.

Comment: All can see edit history and first publish is same like my answer)